# Add linked data into Azure Tables

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure Table `Car` (PK, RK, T, "CarName") and another Azure Table `Color` (PK, RK, T, "ColorName").

```
Car 
0 0 00:00 Tesla
0 1 00:00 Toyota

Color
0 0 00:00 Black
0 1 00:01 White
0 2 00:02 Red
```

How can I add to my `Car` a new property  "Color" to reference an entry in the `Color` table?

I mean, by eg, how to indicate **Toyota** is **Red**? Should it be

```
0 1 00:00 Toyota 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't really one best solution to your question, it is basically a trade-off and what fits best for you.

Please take a look at the guidance document detailing three methods on how to [model one-to-many relationships in Azure Tables](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-table-design-guide.md#one-to-many-relationships) along with the pros and cons of each.

1. Separate entity types, same partition, same table
2. Separate entity types, different partitions or tables or storage
   accounts
3. Denormalize into single entity type

Comment: what I didn't really understand is what kind of data I should use for the `Color` "column".. Should it be a string? How to reference then the White Color, by eg.

Comment: The "foreign key" will need to concatenate both the Partition Key and the Row Key. So in your example, you would have PK: 0 and RK: 2 (for red), which would give you: `0 0 00:00 Tesla 0_2`. Remember that Tables does not support joins, so this is a "foreign key" that is used as a look up only.

Comment: So, in order to recuperate the "red" color name from Tesla I need to split  "0_2" with "_" separator then search for a "0" "2" entry in the `Color` table...

Comment: Correct, once you split, you would have the PK and the RK of where to look in Color